# MATLAB: power function curve fitting

Tags: matlab

I would like to know the MATLAB code form of the power polynomial *y* = *x*<sup>*m*</sup>.
I require the numerical value of *m* by fitting this curve to a set of data. My initial program is as follows:

```
load A   
N = A(:, 1);
t = A(:, 2);    
p = polyfit(log(N), log(t), 1);    
f = (p, t);    
plot(t, N, '-', t, f, '-');
```

My only doubt is the above `polyfit` function used for curve fitting is for the equation *y* = *bx*<sup>*m*</sup> which is not fitting my data set, where I require *b* = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter of [polyfit](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/polyfit.html) is degree of polynomial, *m* in your case.

You can pass parameter larger than *m* to *polyfit*. Then, if your assumption about model is correct *p[m + 1]* will be the largest component of *p* (and close to 1), while others should be close to zero.